# Given three numbers, two are guaranteed equal, find the different number.

Tags: php

For example: A = 2, B = 4 & C = 2 then output should be uniqueNumber(A, B, C) = 4

Comment: please provide more information on how you have tried or how you want it?

Comment: do you need logic for that?

Comment: what if there would be 5 or 10 arguments?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($A==$B)
{
    return $C;
}
if ($A==$C)
{
    return $B;
}
return $A;
```

Comment: Even though this might be what OP is looking for, code-only answers are generally not liked on SO. Include a description of what your code, even if it is quite simple, like this.

Comment: Thank you for your help Robert Columbia...it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This should be a simple logic answer and you can either go with direct comparisons but that might be too hectic in case of more than 3 arguments.

You can try this out as well:

```
$num_arr = [$a,$b,$c];

for($i=0;$i<count($num_arr)-1; $i++)
{
    if(!in_array($num_arr[$i],array_merge(array_slice($num_arr,0,$i),array_slice($num_arr,$i+1))))
        return $num_arr[$i];
}
```

Or simply like this:

```
$num_arr = [$a,$b,$c];

for($i=0;$i<count($num_arr)-1; $i++)
{
    $temp = $num_arr;
    unset($temp[$i]);
    if(!in_array($num_arr[$i],$temp))
        return $num_arr[$i];
}
```

Tried implementing a more generic approach.

Hope it helps.